# How to display panel which is of Singleton class in two different frames at a time?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to display a singleton obj on two different Jframe, but it is displayed only in the Jframe in which the object is added at last ( in example Frame2). Other Jframe is empty. This Singleton class is inherited from Panel and contains a label in it. Can anybody please tell me how can i display this singleton object in two different frame ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
{
public void run() {
 NewJFrame inst = new NewJFrame();
 inst.setTitle("Frame1");
 inst.setSize(300, 300);
 inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 inst.setVisible(true);
 singltonpanel _sin = singltonpanel.instance();
 inst.add(_sin);
 inst.repaint();
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame2");
 frame.setSize(300, 300);
 frame.setVisible(true);
 singltonpanel _sin1 = singltonpanel.instance();
 frame.add(_sin1);
 frame.repaint();
}
});
```

Answer (score 7):

A Swing component is only allowed to have a single parent. You may not add a component to two containers.

From http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html

> Each GUI component can be contained
>   only once. If a component is already
>   in a container and you try to add it
>   to another container, the component
>   will be removed from the first
>   container and then added to the
>   second.

In other words, Swing requires your components to be arranged in a tree-hierarchy.

**Solution:** You basically need to break up your singleton-class into a model class and a view class. (Check out the MVC pattern at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) Then instantiate multiple views of the model.